# Calling an "overloaded member function" in opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, overloading, canny-operator

In OpenCV, some functions have an "overloaded member" counterpart (for example, [Canny edge detection](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga2a671611e104c093843d7b7fc46d24af)).

My question is : how do I call this overloaded function in my code? If I call cv2.Canny(), it will always call the "[standard Canny](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de)" no matter the arguments.

I'm using Python 2.7 (maybe that will be an issue for this problem, compared to C++ ?) and OpenCV 3.1, on Ubuntu 14.

Here is a MWE :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#getting gradient of image in x and y directions
def imgradient(img, sobel):
    sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=sobel)
    sobely = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=sobel)
    return (sobelx,sobely)

#open image
IMG=cv2.imread("path_to_my_image") #replace with actual path
h = IMG.shape[0]; w = IMG.shape[1]

#Canny parameters : thresholds and kernel size
upper=5; lower=5; SIZE_KERNEL=3

#computing gradients (needed as arguments for overloaded Canny)
sobels=imgradient(IMG,3)
sobelx=sobels[0]
sobely=sobels[1];

output=np.zeros((h,w))

#trying to call overloaded Canny
cv2.Canny(sobelx,sobely,output,lower,upper);
#get error "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"
#because the code is actually calling the standard Canny (second link)
edges = cv2.Canny(IMG, lower, upper, apertureSize=SIZE_KERNEL)
#works fine, but this is not the Canny I'm looking for (read this line in Obi-Wan's voice)
```

Thanks

Comment: What function do you expect to call?

Comment: The one in the first link.

Comment: Can you show some code? [mcve]

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [overloaded Canny function](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga2a671611e104c093843d7b7fc46d24af) you are trying to call is available from OpenCV 3.2 . You can see in the doc for [OpenCV 3.1](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de) that the function is not present.

Since you're using OpenCV 3.1, you don't have that function.

You can download the OpenCV 3.2 <s>(still not released) from the [github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/3.2.0-rc) and compile it.</s> from the [main site](http://opencv.org/downloads.html)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a lot, I had no idea 3.2 existed and that I was looking at that documentation. For various reasons, I can't download it right now, but when I'll do it, I'll try it out and accept your answer.

Comment: @Soltius OpenCV 3.2 is now released. You can avoid to compile it yourself ;D

Comment: Wow, they said they'd release in Q4 2016 and they stuck to it ! Thanks :)